# Is there a way to do incremental linting with RuboCop?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a Ruby code base which has been maintained for many years. When I use RuboCop to check the code-style, it will give me thousands of offenses. Is there a way use RuboCop to check only the new added code or new modified code, and only report offenses for that code?

Comment: You can pass the files you want to check to `rubocop`. If you use git, you could easily retrieve a list of modified / new files. Of course, that would still check the whole file.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways in which Rubocop can help you.

If you run

```sh
rubocop --auto-gen-config
```

Rubocop will generate two configuration files for you: a mostly empty `.rubocop.yml`, which only contains one key:

```yaml
inherit_from: .rubocop_todo.yml
```

And a `.rubocop_todo.yml` which *disables* every offense found in your codebase on a per-file basis:

```yaml
# This configuration was generated by
# `rubocop --auto-gen-config`
# on 2020-09-11 06:20:56 UTC using RuboCop version 0.90.0.
# The point is for the user to remove these configuration records
# one by one as the offenses are removed from the code base.
# Note that changes in the inspected code, or installation of new
# versions of RuboCop, may require this file to be generated again.

# Offense count: 1
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
Layout/SpaceAfterMethodName:
  Exclude:
    - 'test.rb'

# Offense count: 1
# Cop supports --auto-correct.
# Configuration parameters: AllowUnusedKeywordArguments, IgnoreEmptyMethods, IgnoreNotImplementedMethods.
Lint/UnusedMethodArgument:
  Exclude:
    - 'test.rb'
```

This file is used for two things:

- If your organization's style guide differs from the default Rubocop config, you can cut&paste the offense from the TODO into the "real" config file and disable it permanently and globally.
- You can use the TODO file as an actual TODO list, and remove the exclusions one-by-one and fix the offenses one-by-one whenever you have time to do them.

Note, however, that exclusions are file-based, not line-based, so you can only disable cops globally or per-file. When you make changes to an existing file, your newly added code will also have those cops disabled, so it is a good idea to enable linting of the file first and fix all existing offenses.

Also note that you will probably have to use the `--exclude-limit COUNT` option, because if there are more than `COUNT` files with the same offense, Rubocop will just disable it globally. The default is 15, so you should set it to a value that is higher than the total number of files in your project.

Another helpful parameter is

```sh
rubocop --safe-auto-correct --disable-uncorrectable
```

Which will safely auto correct all safely auto correctable offenses, and add comments to disable cops for non-correctable offenses.

However, I would argue that this is not actually Rubocop's job in the first place. Your reporting system should have a way of recording a "baseline", and only report deviations from that baseline.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [pronto-rubocop](https://github.com/prontolabs/pronto-rubocop) may do the job